# Efficient datetime evaluation inside dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe where the indexes are date strings. I would like to assign `0` to the values fulfilling a double condition: if the index is between `02:00` and `03:00` and if the value is `>0`

```
df = 
                       P
01/01/2019 00:00:00    0
01/01/2019 01:00:00   -1
01/01/2019 02:00:00    2  --> 0
01/01/2019 03:00:00   -3
01/01/2019 04:00:00    4
01/01/2019 05:00:00   -5
01/01/2019 06:00:00   -6
```

So far, I have done it by evaluating one by one all the indexes but this does not look very efficient to me...

```
h_start = 2
h_stop = 3
for x in range(len(df.index)):
    my_hour = datetime.strptime(df.index[x], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S').hour
    if h_start <= my_hour < h_stop and df.iloc[x][0] > 0:
      df.iloc[x] = 0
```

Is there a more pythonic way (maybe with pandas) to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution you can try out, using [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) to create a mask

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
mask = (df['P'] > 0) & (df.index.isin(df.between_time('02:00', '3:00').index))

df.loc[mask, 'P'] = 0
```

---

```
                     P
idx                   
2019-01-01 00:00:00  0
2019-01-01 01:00:00 -1
2019-01-01 02:00:00  0
2019-01-01 03:00:00 -3
2019-01-01 04:00:00  4
2019-01-01 05:00:00 -5
2019-01-01 06:00:00 -6
```

Comment: this is not working since my indexes are ```string```, not ```DateTime```. Moreover, it should be included in the ```between_time``` the parameter ```include_end=False``` (in my case)